# Creational patterns that depends on object type

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my winform project I have some graphic models-classes: `Rectangle`, `Assosiation line` and `Text`.
Example:

```
public class Rectangle 
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public short Zindex { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public Size Size{ get; set; } 
}
```

And  common Inteface `IPathBuilder` with classes that generates graphic pathes for each model: `RectangleGraphicPathBuilder`, etc. Example:

```
public class RectangleGraphicPathBuilder : IPathBuilder
{
    protected override GraphicsPath Build(IShape inShape )
    {
        var shape = inShape as Rectangle;
        var newPath = new GraphicsPath();
        newPath.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(shape.Location.X, shape.Location.Y, shape.Size.Width, shape.Size.Height));
        return newPath;
    }
}
```

And I need to use some pattern that calls these builders while shapes in collection iterates. Like:

```
forech(IShape shape in shapeColection){
    var path = IPathBuilder.Builder(shape);
}
```

I'll be glad for any tips about it.

Comment: This looks like copying objects, not building new ones... how about putting a Copy or Clone method in IShape, and having each class implement it in their own specific way?

Comment: You mean add PathGenerator method in Model? I suppose that model contains only it's parameters: Color, Size, etc. And ability to bild graphic pathes I want provide for speial service IPathBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method `AddShapeToPath` to the `IShape` interface, which will be specialised for each shape. Call this method in the builder instead of trying to process each shape type.

```
public interface IShape {
    void AddShapeToPath(GraphicsPath path);
}

public class Rectangle: IShape
{
    // properties removed for readability
    public void AddShapeToPath(GraphicsPath path)
    {
        path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, Size.Width, Size.Height));
    }
}

protected override GraphicsPath Build(IShape inShape )
{
    var newPath = new GraphicsPath();
    inShape.AddShapeToPath(newPath);
    return newPath;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that model contains only it's parameters: Color, Size, etc. And ability to bild graphic pathes I want provide for speial service IPathBuilder.

Comment: The shape contains only the data it needs to build itself. If you need to build the path in the shape itself then simply add a method to the interface to provide the path if it needs to be differentiated between shapes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need strategy design pattern. An example of the strategy design pattern implementation is already provided by Samy.